# The Immigration and Refugee Protection Act

Tags: canada, immigration

The first part of [the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/I-2.5/section-38.html) lists conditions where a foreign national is inadmissible on health grounds and the second part lists the exceptions.

Exception (2) (a) talks about "a foreign national who has been determined to be a member of the family class and to be the spouse, common-law partner or child of a sponsor", while Exception (2) (d) talks about "a foreign national who is the spouse, common-law partner, child or other family member of a foreign national referred to in any of paragraphs (a) to (c)".

Could someone please confirm if "a foreign national referred to in any of paragraphs (a) to (c)" mentioned in Exception (2) (d) actually refers to "a sponsor" mentioned in Exception (2) (a)? If so, then are we talking about a foreign national sponsoring another foreign national?

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone please confirm if "a foreign national referred to in any of paragraphs (a) to (c)" mentioned in Exception (2) (d) actually refers to "a sponsor" mentioned in Exception (2) (a)?

It does not.  The effect of paragraph (d) is to extend the benefit of being sponsored (or otherwise covered by paragraphs (a) through (c)) to certain family members of the person covered in those paragraphs.  So, for example, if Alice is a foreign national who is a member of the family class because she is the child of her sponsor, then Alice's child Bob falls under paragraph (d) (if Bob is not a Canadian citizen, of course).

It's easy to get confused if you think only about spouses and partners, because those relationships are reflexive.  But bear in mind that the person covered by (b) or (c) would not normally have a sponsor.

To know who can act as a sponsor, you would have to look at the definition of that term in the regulations (including any judicial rulings affecting the interpretation of the term).  I believe that's here:

> 130 (1) Subject to subsections (2) and (3), a sponsor, for the purpose of sponsoring a foreign national who makes an application for a permanent resident visa as a member of the family class or an application to remain in Canada as a member of the spouse or common-law partner in Canada class under subsection 13(1) of the Act, must be a Canadian citizen or permanent resident who
>
> (a) is at least 18 years of age;
>
> (b) resides in Canada; and
>
> (c) has filed a sponsorship application in respect of a member of the family class or the spouse or common-law partner in Canada class in accordance with section 10.

[Subsections 2 and 3 omitted for brevity]

Source: https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-2002-227/page-18.html#s-130